# Updating header.php in wordpress doesn't update on blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a header.php file in the Theme editor. The theme is Excellence.

Now, I need to change the header logos `href` to point to `example.com` and not `example.com/blog/` for which I've done the following:

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://example.com/">
        <img src="http://example.com/blog/wp-content/themes/excellence/images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
</h1>
```

My computers Chrome, where the changes were made, reflects this perfectly. However, all other devices and my Incognito window, still redirect to `example.com/blog`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sure the cache is cleared on other devices?

Comment: Yeah, trying hard refresh `Ctrl+shift+R` also doesn't work on other devices or other browsers.

Comment: Try to logout on Chrome and check if the link works fine. Log back in and check the link again.

Comment: @Newtt it's `Ctrl + F5` / `Ctrl + Shift + F5` on chrome

Comment: @Nikolas, Tried that. Doesn't work. In fact, on any other browser, logging into the `Theme Editor`, shows the header.php to contain `example.com`. However, the site still shows `example.com/blog`.

Comment: @andyroo, I tried that. My browser has `Ctrl+Shift+R`. `F5` does nothing as far as I could tell

Comment: If you `View Source` does it show as `example.com` or `example.com/blog/`?

Comment: @Eilidh, It shows as `example.com/blog`.

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin..??

Comment: WP Super Cache @SunilChaudhary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be caused by two reasons.

1. Due to the browser caching. This can be solved by clearing the browser cache.
2. Due to the cache plugin. This can be solved by clearing the plugin cache.

one of the above options will solve your problem.